# Making a counter in javascript To-do app

Tags: javascript, events

I have made a little javascript to-do app in order to get better at the language. I am trying to create a counter which increments each time a task is added to the ordered list, but it does not work. Here is my code:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('add-button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var item = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var newItem = document.createElement('li');
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem);
  var count = 0;
  count++;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;


  var removeTask = document.createElement('img');
  removeTask.setAttribute('src', '/images/trash.jpg');
  removeTask.setAttribute('id', 'trash');
  removeTask.addEventListener('click', function() {
    newItem.parentNode.removeChild(newItem);
  });
  newItem.appendChild(removeTask);

});
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <form>
    <h2>Todo App</h2>
    <p>Add a new todo</p>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter an activity......">
    <button type="button" id="add-button">Add Task</button>
  </form>
</div>
<ol id="todoList">
  <h1>Things to do:</h1>
  <div id="counter">0</div>
</ol>
```

Right now it increments to 1 when one clicks but it ends there. I tried making a for loop that loops until the length of the newItem but that did not work at all. How can I make it increment on each time an item is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `count` outside of the scope of the event listener, otherwise you will always increment 0 by 1 for every item added (and 0+1 is always 1). Put the declaration outside of the listener, and increment that value:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('add-button');
var count = 0;


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var item = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var newItem = document.createElement('li');
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem);
  count++;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;


  var removeTask = document.createElement('img');
  removeTask.setAttribute('src', '/images/trash.jpg');
  removeTask.setAttribute('id', 'trash');
  removeTask.addEventListener('click', function() {
    newItem.parentNode.removeChild(newItem);
  });
  newItem.appendChild(removeTask);

});
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <form>
    <h2>Todo App</h2>
    <p>Add a new todo</p>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter an activity......">
    <button type="button" id="add-button">Add Task</button>
  </form>
</div>
<ol id="todoList">
  <h1>Things to do:</h1>
  <div id="counter">0</div>
</ol>
```